# How to locate text in Paper Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I tried to make vertical center for Paper from material-ui.

My code is bellow

```js
const style = {
  height: 150,
  width: 150,
  margin: 20,
  textAlign: 'center',
  rounded: true
};


 render () {
    let { currentTime, isRunning } = this.state;
    let stopWatchTime = this.showCorrectTime(currentTime);
    let buttonName = isRunning ? 'Stop' : 'Start';
    let buttonRole = isRunning ? this.stopTime : this.startTime;

    return (
      <div>
        <TextField
          multiLine
          rows={2}
          rowsMax={4}
         />
        <Paper style={style} zDepth={5} circle >{stopWatchTime}</Paper>
        <button onClick={buttonRole}>{buttonName}</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I tried `verticalAlign` but does not help. Also I did not find options with text in documentation. Please who now, provide info how to centered text inside `Paper` or info how to work with text in general.

Image with example, what I have now

[image: 1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of putting the content directly inside Paper, put that inside a `div` and use `css` properties to align it properly.

Like this:

```
<Paper style={style} zDepth={5} circle >
   <div style={{marginTop: '....'}}> 
      {stopWatchTime}
   </div>
</Paper>
```

Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/o22jy5hs/